# How to send data from jquery to flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to render data as a paginated table as shown below. I added an extra feature which allows me to get a value from a row when its clicked ([see this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html))

```
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I pass this value in `data[0]` to a flask function `process` using an Ajax call so I dont have to refresh the whole page i.e. `process()` refreshes a specified DOM when its done? I'm a novice, please bear with me.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True

@app.route('/')
def index(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

@app.route('/process', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process():
    #Do something with the value
    return render_template('process.html', value=value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Check the documentation of JQuery about ajax.

Comment: It is easy. Just use [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Use flask_restful to make a Flask API server and receive a json as a post from your jQuery script.

Below should give you an idea of what I mean:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class DataHandler(Resource):
  def get(self):
      return stuff

  def post(self):
    try:
      args = request.json
      # handle stuff
      return 200
    except:
      return 400

api.add_resource(DataHandler, '/endpoint_name')
```